# How to place two iframes is the same row

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this code:

```
<div align="center">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="//blockadz.com/ads/show/show.php?   a=6NJWBKLSGP8CY&b=OYEPEGYYZ996L"   style="overflow:hidden;width:468px;height:60px;" frameborder="0"; padding-   bottom: 20px; display:inline-block;></iframe>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY"    target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
</div>
<div align="center">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="//blockadz.com/ads/show/show.php?   a=6NJWBKLSGP8CY&b=OYEPEGYYZ996L"   style="overflow:hidden;width:468px;height:60px;" frameborder="0"; padding-   bottom: 20px; display:inline-block;></iframe>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY"    target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
</div>
```

I want to show in the same row, but don't know how?
I tried adding: `display:inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;`  but nothing changed.

Any help?

Comment: Much of your CSS, including the `display:inline-block`, is outside the "style" attribute....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding CSS float to your main divs

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div align="center">
        <iframe bottom:="" frameborder="0" padding-="" scrolling="no" src="//blockadz.com/ads/show/show.php?%20a=6NJWBKLSGP8CY&b=OYEPEGYYZ996L" style="overflow:hidden;width:468px;height:60px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY" target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
    <div align="center">
        <iframe bottom:="" frameborder="0" padding-="" scrolling="no" src="//blockadz.com/ads/show/show.php?%20a=6NJWBKLSGP8CY&b=OYEPEGYYZ996L" style="overflow:hidden;width:468px;height:60px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY" target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[See in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1c53vq/1/)</kbd>

Comment: float is really better reserved for things that need to be, well, floated; a display:inline-block is really more appropriate here.  (Basically you're getting inline-block as a side effect of the float.)

Answer (score 1):

Two divs with *width 50%*:

**HTML**

```
<div id="first_column">
<div align="center">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CevxZvSJLk8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY" target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="second_column">
<div align="center">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CevxZvSJLk8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://blockadz.com/?a=BuyAds&id=6NJWBKLSGP8CY" target="_blank">Advertise in this spot</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first_column,
#second_column {
  width: 50%;
}

#first_column {
  float:left;
}

#first_column {
  float:right;
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyWrbX

Comment: How could you do 2 rows on the first colums, tkx!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different issues going on here:

1. You have invalid markup on the iframes (some of your CSS is outside the "style" attribute so won't have any effect.)
2. Your "advertise in this spot" divs are full page width, which will interfere with the side-by-side layout you're attempting to apply to the iframes.

The simplest solution is to add parent containers to each set of iframe-plus-link, and apply the layout to those containers.  For clarity here I've pulled your inline CSS out into class declarations, and changed the sizes to fit within the SO layout, but you can adjust this to whatever sizes and styles you like:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px; 
  display:inline-block;
}

iframe {
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px;
}

.ad {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
  <div class="ad">Advertise in this spot</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
  <div class="ad">Advertise in this spot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but first answer was that what i needed. :)

Comment: Be careful about using `float` willy-nilly like that; it can cause other layout issues.  (Other than the misuse of `float`  the two answers are essentially the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add css to the siblings elements (in this case the parent `<div>` element) to make them show in the same line, like

```
div[align] { display: inline-block; }
```

or

```
div[align] { float: left; }
```

and define a width for them (if they are adapting to content width they can get on new line if too big)

```
div[align] { width: 50%; }
iframe { width: 100%; } /* or max-width */
```